# tkinter slideshow how to import image from directory?

Tags: python, tkinter, slideshow

I want to make a tkinter slideshow program and I am referring to [this](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/468841/tkinter-image-slide-show-python) code.

In this code, I should add image like below:

```
 image_files = ['Slide_Farm.gif', ...]
```

But I want to import all image automatically from my folder.
For example, `image_files=['/home/imagefolder/']`
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into the python [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module.

```
import glob
image_files=glob.glob('/home/imagefolder/*.gif')
```